# Difference between source and target in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

Both the source and the target comes under the movable class.So I have understood that both represents something similar to "dragable" as in javascript.(Is my understanding crt?)

> Target Essentially it is Source wrapped in with isSource set to false.
>   Instances of this class can be created from the HTML markup
>   automatically by dojo/parser using data-dojo-type="dojo/dnd/Target".

What exactly is the difference and usage of these two i.e target and source?
In event handling we mean the target as the node where the event occurs.Does the target in dojo means the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct `dojo/dnd` it is used for drag and drop.

> dojo/dnd provides the basic user interface concepts of “drag and drop”
>   where a user interface element it clicked, dragged and then dropped in
>   another location. dojo/dnd uses an “avatar” to represent objects that
>   are being dragged from one location to another

There is not great difference between `source` and `target`

Basically it is for convenience as `target` is a Boolean flag. If it is true, then this object can be used to start the DnD operation, otherwise it can serve only as a target. It is true by default.

I hope it helped.